# Why can't I use "required" and "disabled" at the same time in radio input field?

Tags: html

I want to add `required` property in radio input field and here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>test radio</title>
        <style>
            div.radio{
                background-color:silver;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='procesPost.html' method='POST'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <input type='radio' required name='test' value=1>
                <input type='radio' required name='test' value=2>
            </div>
            <input type='SUBMIT' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works well,I have to select one radio to submit, However, if I want to disable one radio, the `required` constraint will not work

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>test radio</title>
        <style>
            div.radio{
                background-color:silver;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='procesPost.html' method='POST'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <input type='radio' required name='test' value=1>
                <input type='radio' required disabled name='test' value=2>
            </div>
            <input type='SUBMIT' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I can submit the form even though I didn't select any radio.
I wonder why this would happen and how could I solve this problem?

I tested my code in FierFox 32.0.3, RHEL6.2

Comment: Because you have disabled the field, instead of `disabled` use `readonly`

Comment: Have you tried not putting required on the disabled component?

Comment: I tested your second code (verbatim) in Firefox 35, and an attempt at submitting the form without selecting a radio button causes HTML5 form validation message, saying I need to select one of the alternatives. So either Firefox 32 had an odd bug, or there was some other code interfering when you tested.

Comment: Deleted my answer, since I realized I couldn't replicate your problem, only my "solution".  

Have you tried removing the required attribute from the disabled radio input? The required attribute only has to be present on one of the radio elements in the same group, for the entire group to be required (i.e. one of the options has to be chosen). According to the spec, an element must be mutable (i.e. not disabled) in order for the required attribute to be applied. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98a53t9w/

Comment: @PHeiberg I found that I couldn't replicate this problem in Windows,Chrome, So maybe it is just for browser in Red Hat or may be it is just for Firefox?

Comment: @Alaya - I couldn't replicate in neither Chrome, IE 11 or FF on Windows.

Comment: I am not able to reproduced the error using above code. But Problem exist when we are using validation js plugin. (Required not work for disabled Input radio)

Answer (score 11):

According to CBroe:

[www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute):

> Constraint validation: If an element is disabled, it is barred from constraint validation.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#barred-from-constraint-validation:

> A submittable element is a candidate for constraint validation except when a condition has barred the element from constraint validation.

And finally, from the list of Constraint validation steps, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constraint-validation:

> 3.1: If field is not a candidate for constraint validation, then move on to the next element.

That means, a disabled element will just be “passed over” when form validity is checked.

It doesn’t trigger any errors, and has no influence whatsoever on the validation state of the form it belongs to.

The comment is in this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533215